# remove tags inside hyperlink using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I try to remove the span tag (auto generated, I cannot remove them) from this hyperlink:

```
<td class="MyClassID">
   <a href="test.asp?showdetail=&ID=<span>12</span>">test</a>
</td>
```

My query:

```
$(".MyClassID").find("span").contents().unwrap();
```

Won't work... Can someone help me?

Comment: I think this is a span generated by ASP.NET?? -> Use a Literal instead of a Label

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/J3gEG/)

```
$(".MyClassID a").attr('href', function (_, old) {
    return old.replace('<span>', '').replace('</span>', '');
});
```

---

Problem `span` tag is not preset in `.MyClassID`

`span` is inside the `href` attribute of `a` tag.

change `replace` `<span>` and `</span>` with empty string

[.attr( attributeName, function(index, attr) )](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-functionindex--attr)

Comment: You've forgotten the end of your `</span>` tag, but otherwise spot on

Comment: Your fiddle is also incorrect. It produces an attribute of `test.asp?showdetail=&ID=12>`. Note the trailing `>`

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a span generated by ASP.NET.. Instead of a asp:Label use a asp:Literal.. That way there will be no tags generated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var reg = /<span>|</span>/i;
$(".MyClassID").find("a").attr(href,$(".MyClassID").find("a").attr(href).replace(reg,''));
```

Comment: Since you are assuming there is only one `<a>` tag on the page, you should cache your call to `$(".MyClassID").find("a")`

Comment: This will only work if there is only one `<a>` on the page which meets the criteria of `$(".MyClassID").find("a")`. That's not invalid logic since the OP didn't mention anything about multiple instances, but you are calling the same selector twice: `$(".MyClassID").find("a")`. You should cache this in a variable: `var $a = $(".MyClassID").find("a");` ... `$a.attr(href, $a.attr(href).replace(....))` and so on

Comment: @RGraham:It is clear from what op has asked that td contains only one anchor element

Comment: I agree. That's why I was trying to give you advice on how to [improve on the performance of your query](http://mikeadamsnc.com/cache-jquery-selectors-for-better-performance/). Feel free to ignore :)

Comment: @RGraham:Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

try this [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/h46NP/1/)

```
$("a").each(function (){
var id=$(this).attr("href").substring($(this).attr("href").indexOf("<span>"))

var k=$(this).attr("href").substring($(this).attr("href").indexOf("<span>"),0);
    $(this).attr("href",k+$(id).text());
console.log($(this).attr("href"));
});
```

Comment: You are assuming there is only one `<a>` tag on the entire page.

Comment: It works...but it only works for one `<a>` element. Consider the following fiddle using the same code - http://jsfiddle.net/h46NP/

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to use regular expressions and using regular expressions on HTML is a bad idea.

The amaxing thing is DOM has textContent/innerText which gives you just the text inside witout the elements. Jquery gives you [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) that does this for you.

So you can just grab the text and put it back into the element.

```
$(".MyClassID").find("a").each(
    function () {
        var anchor = $(this);
        anchor.html( anchor.text() );
    }
);
```

And if you want, you could also just set the text instead of the html

```
anchor.text( anchor.text() );
```

Answer (score -1):

Your span tags are inside the *attribute* for some bizarre reason. Remove them using replace:

```
$(".MyClassID").find("a").attr("href", function(i, val) {
    return val.replace("<span>", "").replace("</span>", "");
});
```

[Here is a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yxes3/) of the above.

Comment: Downvoter care to comment? Interested in improving on the above working code.