# removing tags inside an email hyperlink with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

refering to [remove tags inside hyperlink using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21285523/remove-tags-inside-hyperlink-using-jquery)

Sorry to bother but now I need to send an email from a hyperlink... unfortunately the previous solutions don't solve the problem :(

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yxes3/1/) work only with the email field

```
$(".MyClassID").find("a").attr("href", function(i, val) {
return val.replace("<span>", "").replace("</span>", "");
});
```

and [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/zr6y5t88/) is better but the body is uncomplete...

```
$("a").each(function (){
var id=$(this).attr("href").substring($(this).attr("href").indexOf("<span>"))

var k=$(this).attr("href").substring($(this).attr("href").indexOf("<span>"),0);
$(this).attr("href",k+$(id).text());
console.log($(this).attr("href"));
});
```

Can anybody help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider usage of regular expression http://jsfiddle.net/yxes3/15/

```
$(".MyClassID").find("a").attr("href", function(i, val) {
    return val.replace(/<\/?span>/gi, "");
});
```

Comment: Thank you ! a quick solving !